# COM Interop with IPC in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, ipc, com-interop

I have a question about IPC with COM Interop objects. I want to create and fill with data COM Interop object in one process (for example Windows Service written in C#). Then I want to get it in another process (console application in C#). I know that COM objects don't serialize and they are unmanaged code. I tried realize solution by .Net Remoting (Windows Service is server, console application is client), but I couldn't get COM Interop object in client (I made .net class inherited from MarshalByRef in shared library, created public property with COM Interop object). Can anyone tell me, what can I do?

Comment: .NET doesn't exactly help you write an out-of-process COM server.  You should consider WCF instead.

Comment: I have legacy COM Object, and I want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM objects are not serializable as such, but when writing a COM object, you're supposed to use sophisticated proxy / stub definition - althouh in general, undercover, you don't really have to think about it, especially if these objects are written using some framework (ATL, delphi, VB6, .NET, etc.).

These proxies / stubs will at compile time or runtime use powerful RPC mechanisms (which is more or less "DCOM") if the client-server communication works out-of-process or across threads (COM "apartments" in fact).

All this to say that if your COM objects are in-process servers and were correctly built, COM provides free services to host them as "[COM+ applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683512.aspx)".

> By creating logical groups of COM components as COM+ applications, you
>   can take advantage of the following benefits of COM+:  Component
>   dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) loaded into processes (DLLHost.exe) on
>   demand and Managed (nothing to do with .NET here) server processes to host components.

If you put your object in a COM+ Application, then you should be able to use it from .NET code just like it was in-process, but now hosted in a special "surrogate" system-provided host process (which happens to be the famous dllhost.exe). You can even configure it to become a full Windows service as shown here in the "Activation" tab of the application configuration:

[image]

Comment: Simon, thanks for your response! So if we choose our COM+ application used as "Server application" then we will have singleton COM Object or not? If not -- who will quite dllhost.exe process after work with object will ended? Sorry, I am noob in COM.

Comment: No it wouldn't be a singleton. The dllhost process recycling can be configured in the "Pooling & Recycling" tab". I suggest you create a test COM+ application and discover the numerous options in the properties dialog (like I shown).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use COM if both sides are .NET applications. It's like buying an expensive modern car, then pulling it by a horse!

First, You can use Remoting. It is easy to implement though not supported anymore and I'm advising not to use it. Anyway, remoting does not need COM Interops. Here is a simple 'Hello World' using remoting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973864.aspx

You can also use WCF (windows Communication Foundation). This one is far more advanced and more suitable for modern applications. This is a Hello World for with WFC: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97204/Implementing-a-Basic-Hello-World-WCF-Service

and this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx

Both technologies support IPC, TCP and HTTP

Comment: Thank you for your time!
I would gladly abandoned from COM Interop, but I can't=(
I know about WCF, but it uses SOAP protocol and COM Interop is not serializable.

Comment: Oh I see. I apologize because should have first asked: "why do you insist on using COM?" There may be a way to do that. Let me try.

Comment: I insist on using COM because there is old legacy program modules developed with COM Technology. These modules have many lines of code and I don't want to rewrite their. In other hand I have MS SQL Database with data necessary to fill one of the COM objects. There is WCF service which gives data from this database. And I want create some permanent entity that will fill COM Object from WCF Service and gives it to another process (for example Console App written also in C#) that will use it. Everything else I want to have only one instance of this filled COM Object (singleton).

Comment: That's why I don't create and fill it in Console App. Maybe it sounds incomprehensible, sorry =)

Comment: @Alireza, I'd disagree about the car/horse analogy, when it comes to running the server and the client app on the same PC. More thoughts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009063/1768303).

Comment: Thanks buddy you have a good point and I liked it :) And of course my metaphor was exaggerated, I myself am still a fan of COM

Comment: @Alireza, glad we're on the same page :)

Comment: @Noseratio, can you give me advice?=) You have good experience with COM Interop as I see.

Comment: @Zheglov, I think I've already have given an advice, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22674920/1768303), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009063/1768303) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22934295/1768303).