# Calling VBS CreateObject("someapp.someapp", "remote PC") for a COM interface on another machine?

Tags: vbscript, com, windows-10, dcom

Disclaimer: Yes, I think this questions boils down to understanding some DCOM basics and what VBS CreateObject actually does/needs:

I have a 3rd party application that offers an automation interface via (D?)COM.
The interface is automatically registered when we install the application and it works fine when running simple VBS scripts locally:

This works fine on the same machine:

```
Dim oAppApi

WScript.Echo "Hello, try to connect ..."
Set oAppApi = CreateObject("theapp.theapp") ' Note that this will either start the application or connect to an already started instance
WScript.Echo oAppApi.APIVersion

oAppApi.DisconnectFromTool
```

This also works on the same machine:

```
Dim oAppApi

WScript.Echo "Hello, try to connect ..."
Set oAppApi = CreateObject("theapp.theapp", "localhost")
WScript.Echo oAppApi.APIVersion

oAppApi.DisconnectFromTool
```

This will fail when run on another PC in the same network:

```
Dim oAppApi

WScript.Echo "Hello, try to connect ..."
Set oAppApi = CreateObject("theapp.theapp", "machineNameWithAppInstalled") ' FAIL: ActiveX component can't create object
```

**What would be neccessary to make this simple VBScript work from the remote machine?**

- Would anything need to be installed on the client machine? (COM proxy DLL or somesuch?)
- Does the `ServerName.TypeName`of [CreateObject](https://ss64.com/vb/createobject.html) need to be known on the client side?
- Do we have to do some `DMCOMCnfg` magic on the server?

---

Additional Details:

Since, from what I know of COM, this might depend on how the stuff is registered, here's my "trace" through the registry for "TheApp.TheApp" on the application PC:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TheApp.TheApp]
@="com.company.toolAPI.theapp.theapp"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TheApp.TheApp\CLSID]
@="{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TheApp.TheApp\CurVer]
@="TheApp.TheApp.7.2"

...


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TheApp.TheApp.7.2]
@="TheApp.TheApp"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TheApp.TheApp.7.2\CLSID]
@="{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}"

...

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}]
@="THEAPP72 Server"
"DllSurrogate"=""
"RunAs"="Interactive User"

...

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}]
@="com.company.toolAPI.theapp.theapp"
"AppID"="{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="com.company.toolAPI.theapp.theapp"
"Assembly"="TheAppCOM, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c9b6e760b808c9f9"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Company/THEAPP7.2/interface/TheAppCOM.DLL"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}\InprocServer32\11.0.0.0]
"Class"="com.company.toolAPI.theapp.theapp"
"Assembly"="TheAppCOM, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c9b6e760b808c9f9"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Company/THEAPP7.2/interface/TheAppCOM.DLL"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0CBEA087-0CC7-4D15-A659-8B3AC68B82E1}\ProgId]
@="TheApp.TheApp"
```

Comment: All of the 3 are necessary somehow. On the server, I'd recommend you use a COM+ application as its much easier and powerful than the manual surrogate (DCOMCnfg points to it): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24732010/403671 . On the client you must have a registered proxy, which for an OLE automation-compatible COM object (such as a .NET COM object) can be just a .tlb (but it can also be the full .Dll if it contains the tlb, or if it's dependencies are ok).

Answer (score 0):

I used RDS.DataSpace to access a 'middle-tier' dcom server.

Example: http://www.oblique.ch/ms/rds25.html#_Toc483670219